# Looking for python module to help "neaten" up a server console window

Tags: python

I'm looking for a Python module/framework/package that will assist me in making a sort of "better" console for my application. As it stands now, STDIN can be "pushed" to new lines by other messages being logged out to the console, therefore making it difficult to read what you are trying to type into a server console if it is a long command, or you are prone to typing errors.

Are there any sort of already existing modules that can help me do this? If it helps, it can be comparable to JLine, (at least I think, I have no first-hand experience with JLine).

Oh, and if you don't understand what I'm talking about, you can check the closest thing I can find of an example [here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFeuo5XTsII&feature=player_detailpage#t=483s) Basically, that bottom line in the console is where all commands are entered, and it doesnt get pushed back when the server is in use; it is sort of static in a sense.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

readline module helps to build a nice prompt with history and auto-completion:

http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html

curses module allows you to separate the console into windows that can be separately scrolled:

http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html

Comment: Thanks, I saw readline. However, I could not find a way to turn it into an actual usable console. Do you know of any examples?